# ReactJs set background image

Tags: reactjs

Having trouble figuring out how to set a `bg` image correctly.
This is what i've tried.

```
backgroundImage: 'url(./static/images/auth_bg.jpg)'
```

- `import Background from './static/images/auth_bg.jpg';`

  - `backgroundImage: 'url(${Background})'`

**Styles**

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
 bg: {
        backgroundImage: 'url(${Background})'
    }
}));

const classes = useStyles();



<div className={classes.bg}>
```

What im getting back

> Module not found: Can't resolve './static/images/auth_bg.jpg' in
>   '/home/h1dd3n/Desktop/Folder/social_blog/blog_react/src/authentication/components'

Beside this it's saying that `Background` is unused import. Next line complains that it can't reslove directory `static`

Comment: well Background is unused since you need to use backticks (`) to render a variable inside a string and you are using single quote

Comment: @buzatto changed it to backsticks, still have the same error. And instead of giving the div a `className, i've tried giving it a styles property. Still same `unresolved` error

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, i totally missed out the point that my current `component` was out or scope.
This fixed it `../../static/images/auth_bg.jpg'`